# Automate Windows Server 2008 Local Policy Changes?

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, scripting

I'm a student assistant in IT at a large organization with several less than cooperative separate IT departments. My little IT group currently doesn't have Active Directory rights to send a Group Policy update to the servers we manage.

I'm supposed to change the Interactive Logon Message Title and Message Text on about 20 machines running Windows Servers 2008. The only way I know how to do this is to Remote Desktop into each one from my Mac and go through the menus but that's a TON of Remote Desktopping and clicking into each machine. There's got to be a better way even with the AD restriction.

I'm more familiar with Macs and I would just write a bash script if these weren't Windows servers. Is there some way to automate this even a little? Maybe Remote Desktop into each one still and then run some kind of cmd line script? I don't even know where to start with Windows scripting.

I'd appreciate ANY insights here! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

There are  ways of scripting something like this but the correct answer in this case is "you are doing it wrong".

This is something that really should be deployed via Active Directory / Group Policy. If you don't have the rights to make these changes yourself you will need to get whatever documentation your organization requires - usually a sign off of a manager / supervisor of the department in question - and a list of systems that need to have the change applied.

For all we know making the changes locally won't stick. Those settings may very well be being deployed from an existing group policy which will override any changes you make.

EDIT:

You can use the resultant set of policy [RSoP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782615(v=ws.10).aspx) to see if the settings will be overridden.

Comment: That's the first thing I said when they told me to do this. They said they can't. Is there a way to see if the message change would be overridden?